# Not able to read .txt file in iGraph python

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I'm trying to read a text file containing space separated columns using python's ***python-igraph*** library. I'm following the documentation but still getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Lucy/PycharmProjects/CS286Project/dataClean.py", line 3, in 
<module>
read_graph= Graph.Read_Ncol('1.txt', directed=True)
NameError: name 'Graph' is not defined
```

**Python code**..

```
  import igraph
  read_graph = Graph.Read_Ncol('1.txt', directed=True)
```

**.txt file**

```
 72QMMSWgOns    boBreak 755 Comedy  35  604 3.91    11  3   hQ-xsBZ_Nqo
 vVa0VC9o3MQ    sagopakajmerat  728 Film & Animation    192 266 4   4   4   bnC17Mr010k
```

Since the spacing between coloums is uneven, is that what is causing this error?

**Edit 1**:

After using the solution provided by @Gwendal Grelier I get the following error

```
  read_graph = igraph.Graph.Read_Ncol('1.txt', directed=True)
   igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at src\foreign.c:243: Parse error in NCOL file, line 1 (syntax error, unexpected ALNUM, expecting NEWLINE), Parse error
```

Comment: I gess your header include this import `from igraph import Graph`. (if not it should). I think you are also missing parenthesis after graph `read_graph = Graph().Read_Ncol(...)`
EDIT: If you write only ìmport igraph` in the header, the use of `Graph()` wont work, you have to specify where does this method comes from ! `igraph.Graph().Read_Ncol(...)`

Comment: After yourr edit: The .txt file might be the problem ! According t the documentation, `Read_Ncol()` reads only .ncol files. http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Read_Ncol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you are missing the module name in the declaration of your `Graph()` method !

```
import igraph
read_graph = igraph.Graph.Read_Ncol('1.txt', directed=True)
```

Should do the trick !

Comment: After trying your solution I'm getting the error shown in the edit above. IS it because of the .txt file format?